# Alfresco Share - Can't find people as site manager after bulk upload

Tags: share, alfresco

I create a lot of users (~350) using User CSV Uploader (/alfresco/service/api/people/upload) and then as site maneger i tried to invite some of this users, but i can't find them.

Steps:

1. create a list of users (using CSV template) - OK
2. upload the list - OK
3. check if the users exist - OK
4. as site manger and alfresco_administrator when i go to  http//mydomain/share/page/site/mysite/invite and search for user (let's say TESTUSER) the user is listed and is allowed to be invited
5. as site manager (not alfresco_administrator) when i go to  http//mydomain/share/page/site/mysite/invite and search for user TESTUSER the user is not listed

The user TESTUSER exist and was created using CSV upload.
I creat manualy another user TESTUSER2 and i follow steps 3,4 and 5. In this case this user TESTUSER2 is listed in both case.

**My question is: There is a possibility to "reindex" all user or i need to create ~300 users manualy.**

Right now LDAP or AD is not an option.

Alfresco 4.2c/Centos 6.4/SOLR (full reindex after 2 days)

Thank You!

Geo

Comment: When you do the upload, does the post response indicate that the correct number of people were found and created?

Comment: Yes. I have 350 user, and all 350 are OK and all are in user console admin.

Comment: Could something be up with your SOLR index? If you follow the Alfresco SOLR troubleshooting guides, do you spot any problems (eg unindexed transactions)?

Comment: Users must accept your invitation. For each user, a workflow has been started...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you able to find the persons via people finder /share/page/people-finder?
If not, are you able to find the persons when appending `[hint:useCQ]`  (forces usage of DB instead of SearchIndex) to your people search term?
If you find the persons using this hint, then your Solr Index is not in sync.

Comment: I am able to find persons via people finder only as admin, other users can't find this persons. If i use `[hint:useCQ]` as user i found persons.  Solr report: `<long name="Count of duplicated transactions in the index">0</long><long name="Count of duplicated acl transactions in the index">0</long><long name="Count of transactions in the index but not the DB">0</long><long name="Count of acl transactions in the index but not the DB">0</long><long name="Count of missing transactions from the Index">0</long><long name="Count of missing acl transactions from the Index">0</long>`;

Comment: Temporary i altered **potentialmembers.get.js** and i added `filter=filter+" [hint:useCQ]";` and it works. Now i must test solr configuration to see which is better. Thank you.